# How to scrape more than 100 google pages in one pass

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, python-requests, google-custom-search

I am using the requests library in python to `GET` data from google results. https://www.google.com.pk/#q=pizza&num=10 will return first 10 results of google as I mentioned `num=10`. Ultimately https://www.google.com.pk/#q=pizza&num=100 will return 100 results of google results.

But

If i write any number more than 100 let https://www.google.com.pk/#q=pizza&num=200 , google is still returning first 100 results

How can I get more than 100 in one pass?

Code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.google.com/search'
my_headers = { 'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/11.0' }
payload = { 'q' : pizza, 'start' : '0', 'num' : 200 }
r = requests.get( url, params = payload, headers = my_headers )
```

In "r" I am getting only URL's of google first 100 results, not 200

Comment: Google enforced limit, maximum number of results per page is 100.

Comment: It's not 100 pages, it's 100 results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a more programmatic api from google to get the results vs. trying to screen scrape the human search interface, there's no error checking or assertion this is complies with all google T&Cs, suggest you look into the details of using this url:

```
import requests

def search(query, pages=4, rsz=8):
    url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web'
    params = {
        'v': 1.0,     # Version
        'q': query,   # Query string
        'rsz': rsz,   # Result set size - max 8
    }

    for s in range(0, pages*rsz+1, rsz):
        params['start'] = s
        r = requests.get(url, params=params)
        for result in r.json()['responseData']['results']:
            yield result
```

E.g. getting 200 results for 'google':

```
>>> list(search('google', pages=24, rsz=8))
[{'GsearchResultClass': 'GwebSearch',
  'cacheUrl': 'http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:y14FcUQOGl4J:www.google.com',
  'content': 'Search the world&#39;s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. \n<b>Google</b> has many special features to help you find exactly what you&#39;re looking\xa0...',
  'title': '<b>Google</b>',
  'titleNoFormatting': 'Google',
  'unescapedUrl': 'https://www.google.com/',
  'url': 'https://www.google.com/',
  'visibleUrl': 'www.google.com'},
  ...
]
```

To use Google's Custom Search API you need to sign up as a developer. You get 100 free queries (I'm not sure if that is API calls or it allows pagination of the same query to count as 1 query) a day:

- Sign up @ https://console.developers.google.com
- Create a project
- Create a `key`
- Enable Custom Search API
- Create a Custom Search Engine @ https://cse.google.com

  - Use a dummy site to initialise the CSE
  - Edit the CSE to search the entire web
  - Delete the dummy site
- Get the CSE reference (look at the public URL for `cx=<cse reference>`)

The you can use `requests` to make the query:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1'
params = {
    'key': '<key>',
    'cx': '<cse reference>',
    'q': '<search>',
    'num': 10,
    'start': 1
}

resp = requests.get(url, params=params)
results = resp.json()['items']
```

With `start` you can do a similar pagination to the above.

There are lots of other parameters available you can look at the REST documentation for the CSE: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#request

Google also has a client-api library: `pip install google-api-python-client` you can also use:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
service = discovery.build('customsearch', 'v1', developerKey='<key>')
params = {
    'q': '<query>',
    'cx': '<cse reference>',
    'num': 10,
    'start': 1
}
query = service.cse().list(**params)
results = query.execute()['items']
```

Comment: Well thanks for it, It is giving result in first few attempts, after that it is not retrieving any result, might be google starts blocking my IP? Any solution?

Comment: Officially the AJAX search url is deprecated and in fact most forms of this url was deleted several years ago, this one particular form was presumably missed. There are API search limits. The official way to programmatically access google is through  the Custom Search API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/ and you will need to sign up for a key - there are significant restrictions on this and you will need to pay if you want full access.

Comment: NP. You get 100 queries a day with the CSE before you need to start paying.

Answer (score -1):

You can use browser automation for this purpose. I have used that to scrape list of images. Using browser automation, you can click on next or previous buttons and get results scrapped. I am unable to paste code.